# Adding UIButton to subview not working

Tags: ios, uibutton, subview

I'm trying to add 16 UIButton in code to a subview of my main view:

```
internView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, 16, (self.view.frame.size.width - 16), (self.view.frame.size.height - 16) - 60)];
internView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


for (int rij = 0; rij < 4; rij++) //4 rows
{
    for (int kolom = 0; kolom < 4; kolom++) //4 colomns
    {

        CGFloat x = (((width + spacing) * kolom) + spacing);
        CGFloat y = (((height + spacing) * rij) + spacing);
        int tag = ((4 * rij) + kolom);


        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];

        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        [button setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[projects objectAtIndex:tag]thumbnailImage]]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(getDetail:) forControlEvents:UIControlStateNormal];

        button.tag = tag;

        NSLog(@"%i",button.tag);

        [internView addSubview:button];

    }
}

[self.view addSubview:internView];
```

The subview 'internview' is visible (as i made it white background) on the main view but the buttons aren't visible.

Also my log shows the tag of the button which goes from 0..15, so I know they are being made but simple aren't added to the subview 'internview'

Can't really see what I'm missing or doing wrong here..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your code to :

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
```

In your version you have:

1. Memory leak because you have created buttons two times
2. [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; returns new button
   with CGRectZero frame

Comment: Thanks a lot. not initializing the frame was the point with my view. I;ve set it and the button shows up, but with the wrong orientations! It's totally weird why it appears in portrait orientation, while my app come in landscape mode, and come on! the image must appear in the right orientation... :-/